# How to get same the same results using networkx spring_layout (Python) and layout_with_fr (R)

Tags: python, r, plot, graph, networkx

I am trying to visualize a Watts–Strogatz model (n=400, k=2, beta=0.02) in the same manner in Python as R. In R I can get a really nice circular layout using the Fruchterman-Reingold layout.

```
library(igraph)
library(qgraph)

g <- sample_smallworld(1, 400,  1, 0.02);
l <-layout_with_fr(g)
adj <- get.adjacency(g)

qgraph(adj, layout=l)
```

[image: R FR graph]

But when I try to reproduce this in Python (using NetworkX to represent and draw the network), I get:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

g = nx.watts_strogatz_graph(400, 2, 0.02)
nx.draw(g, pos=nx.drawing.spring_layout(g, iterations=500), node_size=25)
plt.show()
```

[image: FR networkx]

I know they essentially show the same thing, using the same algorithm, but the circular layout of the R version looks much more appealing. I tried tweaking the amount of iterations, but this didn't help much. I also tried looking for different networkx layout algorithms, but there were none I was really satisfied with.

Is there a way I can reproduce this in Python using a networkx graph?

Comment: Why not use igraph in python too?

Comment: My implementation is already in networkx and I am trying to reproduce the figure from another repo that is using igraph.

Comment: I'd imagine a `pos = nx.kamada_kawai_layout(g)` layout to be more suited

Comment: Yeah I agree, but as the goal is to reproduce the figure of another repository, it's not really an option here.